# 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference ParseGeoPoints

Tags: android, parse-platform, geolocation

I want to query parse to return list of names stored on the Parse Cloud. I am implemented geoLocation and I am using getLatitude and getLongitutude to ParseGeoPoint to get the list of names.

```
public class TakePhotoActivity extends BaseActivity implements RevealBackgroundView.OnStateChangeListener, LocationListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        CameraHostProvider {
    public static final String ARG_REVEAL_START_LOCATION = "reveal_start_location";

    private static final Interpolator ACCELERATE_INTERPOLATOR = new AccelerateInterpolator();
    private static final Interpolator DECELERATE_INTERPOLATOR = new DecelerateInterpolator();
    private static final int STATE_TAKE_PHOTO = 0;
    private static final int STATE_SETUP_PHOTO = 1;

    /*
   * Define a request code to send to Google Play services This code is returned in
   * Activity.onActivityResult
   */
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    /*
     * Constants for location update parameters
     */
    // Milliseconds per second
    private static final int MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND = 1000;

    // The update interval
    private static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 5;

    // A fast interval ceiling
    private static final int FAST_CEILING_IN_SECONDS = 1;

    // Update interval in milliseconds
    private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND
            * UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS;

    // A fast ceiling of update intervals, used when the app is visible
    private static final long FAST_INTERVAL_CEILING_IN_MILLISECONDS = MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND
            * FAST_CEILING_IN_SECONDS;

    @Bind(R.id.vRevealBackground)
    RevealBackgroundView vRevealBackground;
    @Bind(R.id.vPhotoRoot)
    View vTakePhotoRoot;
    @Bind(R.id.vShutter)
    View vShutter;
    @Bind(R.id.ivTakenPhoto)
    ImageView ivTakenPhoto;
    @Bind(R.id.vUpperPanel)
    ViewSwitcher vUpperPanel;
    @Bind(R.id.vLowerPanel)
    ViewSwitcher vLowerPanel;
    @Bind(R.id.cameraView)
    CameraView cameraView;
    @Bind(R.id.rvFilters)
    RecyclerView rvFilters;
    @Bind(R.id.btnTakePhoto)
    Button btnTakePhoto;

    private float radius;
    private float lastRadius;
    private boolean pendingIntro;
    private int currentState;

    private Location lastLocation;
    private Location currentLocation;

    // A request to connect to Location Services
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;

    // Stores the current instantiation of the location client in this object
    private GoogleApiClient locationClient;


    private File photoPath;

    public static void startCameraFromLocation(int[] startingLocation, Activity startingActivity) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(startingActivity, TakePhotoActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(ARG_REVEAL_START_LOCATION, startingLocation);
        startingActivity.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_take_photo);
        updateStatusBarColor();
        updateState(STATE_TAKE_PHOTO);
        setupRevealBackground(savedInstanceState);
        setupPhotoFilters();
        radius = InstaMaterialApplication.getSearchDistance();
        lastRadius = radius;

        // Create a new global location parameters object
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();

        // Set the update interval
        locationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        // Use high accuracy
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        // Set the interval ceiling to one minute
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(FAST_INTERVAL_CEILING_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        // Create a new location client, using the enclosing class to handle callbacks.
        locationClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();


        vUpperPanel.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                vUpperPanel.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                pendingIntro = true;
                vUpperPanel.setTranslationY(-vUpperPanel.getHeight());
                vLowerPanel.setTranslationY(vLowerPanel.getHeight());
                return true;
            }
        });


    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void updateStatusBarColor() {
        if (Utils.isAndroid5()) {
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(0xff111111);
        }
    }

    private void setupRevealBackground(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        vRevealBackground.setFillPaintColor(0xFF16181a);
        vRevealBackground.setOnStateChangeListener(this);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            final int[] startingLocation = getIntent().getIntArrayExtra(ARG_REVEAL_START_LOCATION);
            vRevealBackground.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreDraw() {
                    vRevealBackground.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                    vRevealBackground.startFromLocation(startingLocation);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        } else {
            vRevealBackground.setToFinishedFrame();
        }
    }


    FiltersQueryAdapter mainAdapter = new FiltersQueryAdapter(this, PhotoFiltersAdapter.class
            , new ParseRecyclerQueryAdapter.QueryFactory() {
        public ParseQuery create() {
            Location myLoc = (currentLocation == null) ? lastLocation : currentLocation;
            ParseQuery query = ParseQuery.getQuery("PlaceFilters");
            //query.include("user");
            query.orderByAscending("GeoArea");
            query.whereWithinKilometers("GeoArea", geoPointFromLocation(myLoc), radius);
            query.setLimit(6);
            return query;
        }
    });


    private void setupPhotoFilters() {
        rvFilters.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rvFilters.setAdapter(mainAdapter);
        rvFilters.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        cameraView.onResume();

        // Get the latest search distance preference
        radius = InstaMaterialApplication.getSearchDistance();
        // Checks the last saved location to show cached data if it's available
        if (lastLocation != null) {
            // If the search distance preference has been changed, move
            // map to new bounds.
            if (lastRadius != radius) {
                // Save the current radius
                lastRadius = radius;
                doListQuery();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        cameraView.onPause();
    }

    /*
   * Called when the Activity is no longer visible at all. Stop updates and disconnect.
   */
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        // If the client is connected
        if (locationClient.isConnected()) {
            stopPeriodicUpdates();
        }

        // After disconnect() is called, the client is considered "dead".
        locationClient.disconnect();

        super.onStop();
    }

    /*
  * Called when the Activity is restarted, even before it becomes visible.
  */
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // Connect to the location services client
        locationClient.connect();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        // Choose what to do based on the request code
        switch (requestCode) {

            // If the request code matches the code sent in onConnectionFailed
            case CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST:

                switch (resultCode) {
                    // If Google Play services resolved the problem
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:

                        if (InstaMaterialApplication.APPDEBUG) {
                            // Log the result
                            Log.d(InstaMaterialApplication.APPTAG, "Connected to Google Play services");
                        }

                        break;

                    // If any other result was returned by Google Play services
                    default:
                        if (InstaMaterialApplication.APPDEBUG) {
                            // Log the result
                            Log.d(InstaMaterialApplication.APPTAG, "Could not connect to Google Play services");
                        }
                        break;
                }

                // If any other request code was received
            default:
                if (InstaMaterialApplication.APPDEBUG) {
                    // Report that this Activity received an unknown requestCode
                    Log.d(InstaMaterialApplication.APPTAG, "Unknown request code received for the activity");
                }
                break;
        }
    }


    @OnClick(R.id.btnTakePhoto)
    public void onTakePhotoClick() {
        btnTakePhoto.setEnabled(false);
        cameraView.takePicture(true, true);
        animateShutter();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btnAccept)
    public void onAcceptClick() {
        PublishActivity.openWithPhotoUri(this, Uri.fromFile(photoPath));
    }

    /*
  * Verify that Google Play services is available before making a request.
  *
  * @return true if Google Play services is available, otherwise false
  */
    private boolean servicesConnected() {
        // Check that Google Play services is available
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        // If Google Play services is available
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {
            if (InstaMaterialApplication.APPDEBUG) {
                // In debug mode, log the status
                Log.d(InstaMaterialApplication.APPTAG, "Google play services available");
            }
            // Continue
            return true;
            // Google Play services was not available for some reason
        } else {
            // Display an error dialog
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, 0);
            if (dialog != null) {
                ErrorDialogFragment errorFragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();
                errorFragment.setDialog(dialog);
                errorFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), InstaMaterialApplication.APPTAG);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    /*
   * Called by Location Services when the request to connect the client finishes successfully. At
   * this point, you can request the current location or start periodic updates
   */
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        if (InstaMaterialApplication.APPDEBUG) {
            Log.d("Location Connected", InstaMaterialApplication.APPTAG);
        }
        currentLocation = getLocation();
        startPeriodicUpdates();
    }

    /*
   * Called by Location Services if the connection to the location client drops because of an error.
   */
    public void onDisconnected() {
        if (InstaMaterialApplication.APPDEBUG) {
            Log.d("Location Disconnected", InstaMaterialApplication.APPTAG);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(InstaMaterialApplication.APPTAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has been suspend");
    }

    /*
   * Called by Location Services if the attempt to Location Services fails.
   */
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects. If the error has a resolution, try
        // sending an Intent to start a Google Play services activity that can resolve error.
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {

                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);

            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {

                if (InstaMaterialApplication.APPDEBUG) {
                    // Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original PendingIntent
                    Log.d(InstaMaterialApplication.APPTAG, "An error occurred when connecting to location services.", e);
                }
            }
        } else {
            // If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the user with the error.
            showErrorDialog(connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    /*
   * Report location updates to the UI.
   */
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        currentLocation = location;
        if (lastLocation != null
                && geoPointFromLocation(location)
                .distanceInKilometersTo(geoPointFromLocation(lastLocation)) < 0.01) {
            // If the location hasn't changed by more than 10 meters, ignore it.
            return;
        }
        lastLocation = location;
        // Update map radius indicator
        doListQuery();
    }

    /*
   * In response to a request to start updates, send a request to Location Services
   */
    private void startPeriodicUpdates() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                locationClient, locationRequest, this);
    }

    /*
     * In response to a request to stop updates, send a request to Location Services
     */
    private void stopPeriodicUpdates() {
        locationClient.disconnect();
    }

    /*
   * Get the current location
   */
    private Location getLocation() {
        // If Google Play Services is available
        if (servicesConnected()) {
            // Get the current location
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            }
            return LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(locationClient);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /*
   * Set up a query to update the list view
   */
    private void doListQuery() {
        Location myLoc = (currentLocation == null) ? lastLocation : currentLocation;
        // If location info is available, load the data
        if (myLoc != null) {
            // Refreshes the list view with new data based
            // usually on updated location data.
           // mainAdapter.;
        }
    }

    /*
   * Helper method to get the Parse GEO point representation of a location
   */
    private ParseGeoPoint geoPointFromLocation(Location loc) {
        return new ParseGeoPoint(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude());
    }

    /*
 * Show a dialog returned by Google Play services for the connection error code
 */
    private void showErrorDialog(int errorCode) {
        // Get the error dialog from Google Play services
        Dialog errorDialog =
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(errorCode, this,
                        CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);

        // If Google Play services can provide an error dialog
        if (errorDialog != null) {

            // Create a new DialogFragment in which to show the error dialog
            ErrorDialogFragment errorFragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();

            // Set the dialog in the DialogFragment
            errorFragment.setDialog(errorDialog);

            // Show the error dialog in the DialogFragment
            errorFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), InstaMaterialApplication.APPTAG);
        }
    }

    /*
   * Define a DialogFragment to display the error dialog generated in showErrorDialog.
   */
    public static class ErrorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
        // Global field to contain the error dialog
        private Dialog mDialog;

        /**
         * Default constructor. Sets the dialog field to null
         */
        public ErrorDialogFragment() {
            super();
            mDialog = null;
        }

        /*
         * Set the dialog to display
         *
         * @param dialog An error dialog
         */
        public void setDialog(Dialog dialog) {
            mDialog = dialog;
        }

        /*
         * This method must return a Dialog to the DialogFragment.
         */
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return mDialog;
        }
    }



    private void animateShutter() {
        vShutter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        vShutter.setAlpha(0.f);

        ObjectAnimator alphaInAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(vShutter, "alpha", 0f, 0.8f);
        alphaInAnim.setDuration(100);
        alphaInAnim.setStartDelay(100);
        alphaInAnim.setInterpolator(ACCELERATE_INTERPOLATOR);

        ObjectAnimator alphaOutAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(vShutter, "alpha", 0.8f, 0f);
        alphaOutAnim.setDuration(200);
        alphaOutAnim.setInterpolator(DECELERATE_INTERPOLATOR);

        AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
        animatorSet.playSequentially(alphaInAnim, alphaOutAnim);
        animatorSet.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                vShutter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        animatorSet.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStateChange(int state) {
        if (RevealBackgroundView.STATE_FINISHED == state) {
            vTakePhotoRoot.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (pendingIntro) {
                startIntroAnimation();
            }
        } else {
            vTakePhotoRoot.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    private void startIntroAnimation() {
        vUpperPanel.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(400).setInterpolator(DECELERATE_INTERPOLATOR);
        vLowerPanel.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(400).setInterpolator(DECELERATE_INTERPOLATOR).start();
    }

    @Override
    public CameraHost getCameraHost() {
        return new MyCameraHost(this);
    }


    class MyCameraHost extends SimpleCameraHost {

        private Camera.Size previewSize;

        public MyCameraHost(Context ctxt) {
            super(ctxt);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean useFullBleedPreview() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public Camera.Size getPictureSize(PictureTransaction xact, Camera.Parameters parameters) {
            return previewSize;
        }

        @Override
        public Camera.Parameters adjustPreviewParameters(Camera.Parameters parameters) {
            Camera.Parameters parameters1 = super.adjustPreviewParameters(parameters);
            previewSize = parameters1.getPreviewSize();
            return parameters1;
        }

        @Override
        public void saveImage(PictureTransaction xact, final Bitmap bitmap) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    showTakenPicture(bitmap);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void saveImage(PictureTransaction xact, byte[] image) {
            super.saveImage(xact, image);
            photoPath = getPhotoPath();
        }
    }

    private void showTakenPicture(Bitmap bitmap) {
        vUpperPanel.showNext();
        vLowerPanel.showNext();
        ivTakenPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        updateState(STATE_SETUP_PHOTO);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (currentState == STATE_SETUP_PHOTO) {
            btnTakePhoto.setEnabled(true);
            vUpperPanel.showNext();
            vLowerPanel.showNext();
            updateState(STATE_TAKE_PHOTO);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    private void updateState(int state) {
        currentState = state;
        if (currentState == STATE_TAKE_PHOTO) {
            vUpperPanel.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_from_right);
            vLowerPanel.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_from_right);
            vUpperPanel.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_to_left);
            vLowerPanel.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_to_left);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ivTakenPhoto.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }, 400);
        } else if (currentState == STATE_SETUP_PHOTO) {
            vUpperPanel.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_from_left);
            vLowerPanel.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_from_left);
            vUpperPanel.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_to_right);
            vLowerPanel.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_to_right);
            ivTakenPhoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Logcat:

```
02-16 17:32:40.700 22343-22343/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.google.peep, PID: 22343
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.peep/com.google.peep.activity.TakePhotoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2484)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1394)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
                                                       com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
                                                       at com.google.peep.activity.TakePhotoActivity.geoPointFromLocation(TakePhotoActivity.java:501)
                                                       at com.google.peep.activity.TakePhotoActivity.access$300(TakePhotoActivity.java:66)
                                                       at com.google.peep.activity.TakePhotoActivity$3.create(TakePhotoActivity.java:223)
                                                       at com.javon.parserecyclerviewadapter.ParseRecyclerQueryAdapter.loadParseData(ParseRecyclerQueryAdapter.java:96)
                                                       at com.javon.parserecyclerviewadapter.ParseRecyclerQueryAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(ParseRecyclerQueryAdapter.java:176)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapterInternal(RecyclerView.java:886)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(RecyclerView.java:847)
                                                       at com.google.peep.activity.TakePhotoActivity.setupPhotoFilters(TakePhotoActivity.java:232)
                                                       at com.google.peep.activity.TakePhotoActivity.onCreate(TakePhotoActivity.java:152)
```

Comment: please reduce the post to the relevant part of code where error occurs...

Comment: `geoPointFromLocation(lastLocation)) ` method causing issue because `lastLocation` is null

Comment: try it as : `if (lastLocation != null){
  if(geoPointFromLocation(location)
                .distanceInKilometersTo(geoPointFromLocation(lastLocation)) < 0.01) {   return; }}`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Still returns the same error

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK No Luck its still return Null Pointer Exception

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your getlocation is before the google api client actually connects,pass setup photofilters in onConnected and it will run.Tatasthu!

Comment: Thanks a million finally it worked no one could answer it so far! Treat yourself a beer 